# pixi.loader.shared - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shared')

Tags: loader, pixi.js

As the title says, the loader in pixi js is not working

I have tried different versions of the declaration but none worked.

```
let loader = new PIXI.Loader.shared;
loader.add('tileset', './images/spritesheet.json').load(setup);

function setup(loader, resources){
    const textures = [];
    for(let i = 1; i<13;i++){
        const texture = PIXI.Texture.from(`spritesheet${i}.png`);
        textures.push(texture);
    }}
```

Versions I have tried:

```
let loader = new PIXI.loader.shared;
const loader = new PIXI.Loader();
const loader = new PIXI.loader();
```

I don't have it imported at the beginning of the file as I get error for it (and neither was in the tutorial I followed)